# Need help verifying assembly code

Tags: assembly, gdb, segmentation-fault, x86-64, cpu-registers

I have this assembly which compiles fine but gets a segmentation fault on restore. Can someone verify it .This is for x86_64 architecture

```
save_context:

mov     %rdi,%rax           /* Get our context pointer */
                            /* Don't need to save A */
mov     %rbx, 16(%rax)      /* Save B */
mov     %r12, 24(%rax)      /* Save r12 */
mov     %r13, 32(%rax)      /* Save r13 (8*3+16)*/
mov     %r14, 40(%rax)      /* Save r13 */
mov     %r15, 48(%rax)      /* Save r13 */

mov     %rbp, 56(%rax)      /* Save frame pointer */
mov     %rsp, 64(%rax)      /* Save stack pointer */

mov     (%rsp), %rdx        /* Fetch our return address */
mov     %rdx, (%rax)        /* Save our return address */

xor     %rax,%rax           /* Construct return code of 1 */
inc     %rax

ret
```

Restore goes something like this

```
restore_context:

mov     %rdi,%rax       /* Get our context pointer */       

mov     64(%rax), %rsp  /* Restore stack pointer */ 

mov     (%rax), %rdx    /* Fetch our return address */  
mov     %rdx, (%rsp)    

mov     16(%rax),%rbx   /* Restore B */
mov     24(%rax), %r12  /* Restore r12 */   
mov     32(%rax), %r13  /* Restore r13 */   
mov     40(%rax), %r14  /* Restore r14 */
mov     48(%rax), %r15  /* Restore r15 */
mov     56(%rax), %rbp  /* Restore frame pointer */

xor     %rax,%rax       /* Return 0 */
ret
```

When I use the gdb to debug the function i get this .After the segmentation fault.

```
   0x0000000000424c4c <+0>:     mov    %rdi,%rax
   0x0000000000424c4f <+3>:     mov    0x18(%rax),%rsp
   0x0000000000424c53 <+7>:     mov    (%rax),%rbx
=> 0x0000000000424c56 <+10>:    mov    %rbx,(%rsp)
   0x0000000000424c5a <+14>:    mov    0x10(%rax),%rbx
   0x0000000000424c5e <+18>:    mov    0x20(%rax),%rbp
   0x0000000000424c62 <+22>:    mov    0x28(%rax),%r12
   0x0000000000424c66 <+26>:    mov    0x30(%rax),%r13
   0x0000000000424c6a <+30>:    mov    0x38(%rax),%r14
   0x0000000000424c6e <+34>:    mov    0x40(%rax),%r15
   0x0000000000424c72 <+38>:    xor    %rax,%rax
   0x0000000000424c75 <+41>:    retq   
   0x0000000000424c76 <+42>:    nop
   0x0000000000424c77 <+43>:    nop
```

disasseble save_context

```
  0x0000000000424c1c <+0>:     mov    %rdi,%rax
  0x0000000000424c1f <+3>:     mov    %rbx,0x10(%rax)
  0x0000000000424c23 <+7>:     mov    %rsp,0x18(%rax)
  0x0000000000424c27 <+11>:    mov    %rbp,0x20(%rax)
  0x0000000000424c2b <+15>:    mov    %r12,0x28(%rax)
  0x0000000000424c2f <+19>:    mov    %r13,0x30(%rax)
  0x0000000000424c33 <+23>:    mov    %r14,0x38(%rax)
  0x0000000000424c37 <+27>:    mov    %r15,0x40(%rax)
  0x0000000000424c3b <+31>:    mov    (%rsp),%rdx
  0x0000000000424c3f <+35>:    mov    %rdx,(%rax)
  0x0000000000424c42 <+38>:    xor    %rax,%rax
  0x0000000000424c45 <+41>:    inc    %rax
  0x0000000000424c48 <+44>:    retq   
  0x0000000000424c49 <+45>:    nopl   (%rax)
```

More info about the context

save_context(context)
context = {4243415, 0, 0, 4242944, 140737488348624, 0, 0, 140737488348368, 140737488348312, 0}

restore_context(new_context)
new_context= {4249788, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6719200, 6719184, 0, 0}

It fails after restore context. i tried save_context and then restore_context. That works. Just checking if something is wrong with the context and new context for 64bit ?!?!

Here is the 32bit version

```
save_context:

movl    4(%esp),%eax        /* Get our context pointer */
                            /* Don't need to save A */
movl    %ebx, 12(%eax)      /* Save B */
movl    %esi, 16(%eax)      /* Save SI */
movl    %edi, 20(%eax)      /* Save DI */
movl    %ebp, 24(%eax)      /* Save frame pointer */
movl    %esp, 28(%eax)      /* Save stack pointer */

movl    0(%esp), %edx       /* Fetch our return address */
movl    %edx,  0(%eax)      /* Save our return address */

xorl    %eax,%eax           /* Construct return code of 1 */
incl    %eax
    ret
```

Restore Context:

```
restore_context:
movl    4(%esp),%eax        /* Get our context pointer */

movl    28(%eax), %esp      /* Restore stack pointer */
movl    0(%eax),%edx        /* Get our return address */
movl    %edx, 0(%esp)       /* Put it on the stack in the right
                            spot. */

movl    12(%eax),%ebx       /* Restore B */

movl    16(%eax), %esi      /* Restore SI */
movl    20(%eax), %edi      /* Restore DI */
movl    24(%eax), %ebp      /* Restore frame pointer */

xorl    %eax,%eax       /* Return 0 */
    ret
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Return address is not at `8(%rbp)`, you haven't set up `rbp` to point anywhere (unless it's implicitly set up by the caller).

Comment: @Jester : I thought in x86_64 %8(rbp) has the return address, atleast thats what i read in ABI . How do I set it ?

Comment: Return address is at `(%rsp)`. If you use the legacy function prologue of `push %rbp; mov %rsp, %rbp` then the same location will indeed be also addressable as `8(%rbp)`.

Comment: @Jester Thanks .. So if return address is in rsp Can i do something like " mov (%rsp), %rdx .. mov %rdx, (%rax)" .  Will this work ??!?? I cant use push instruction

Comment: Yes that looks like it should work.

Comment: @Jester :: Still same error. Fails at retq. Can you tell me how to debug this ? Need to figure this out soon, Please help !!!

Comment: You forgot the `()` around the `rsp` ...

Comment: Nope that still dint work.. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: And around the `rax` too ;) Come on, you got it right in the comment a little further up...

Comment: @Jester :) Thanks i tried that aswell.. But yet I am not getting it. The disassemble output changed. Its throwing a segmentation fault on a different line now. Please have a look

Comment: Disassembly doesn't match source, you load `rsp` from `0x18(%rdx)`. Make sure that's correct.

Comment: @Jester: I think i posted the wrong log. But yea I have used rax. rsp loads from 0x18(rax) only. Same error.

Comment: My real worry was the offset ... does that match what you used in the save code? Did you verify that the correct `rsp` is being restored?

Comment: @Jester yea itseems like that .It matches the save code also %rsp,0x18(%rax) . Have the look at the disassemble save_context output. I don't find any anomaly here ?!?!?!

Comment: Seems to work fine here.

Comment: @Jester : How are you testing this on your end ?

Comment: I call `save_context` then `restore_context` which then goes back to doing `restore_context` in an endless loop (haha).

Comment: @Jester Haha.. that seems to work for me too...I tried with the same context.. In the code i switch to a new context. Maybe i have some errors with the new context.

Comment: @Jester : Can you have a look at the input args, maybe something is wrong in that

Comment: `new_context` should of course come from a previous `save_context`, are you sure you didn't corrupt that? How about you post complete code?

Comment: @Jester : The code is pretty huge. It goes through a lot of files And i do a similar context switch for i386(context to new_context) and it works. Why will it give a segmentation fault now ?

Answer (score 4):

First of all I put the save and restore side by side (and shuffle the restore instructions) so I could see whether the offsets were awry. It looks good from that prospective.

```
save_context:                restore_context:

mov     %rdi,%rax            mov     %rdi,%rax

mov     %rbx, 16(%rax)       mov     16(%rax),%rbx
mov     %r12, 24(%rax)       mov     24(%rax), %r12
mov     %r13, 32(%rax)       mov     32(%rax), %r13
mov     %r14, 64(%rax)       mov     64(%rax), %r14
mov     %r15, 48(%rax)       mov     48(%rax), %r15

mov     %rbp, 56(%rax)       mov     56(%rax), %rbp
mov     %rsp, 64(%rax)       mov     64(%rax), %rsp

mov     %rdx, (%rsp)         mov     (%rsp), %rdx
mov     %rdx, (%rax)         mov     (%rax), %rdx

xor     %rax,%rax            xor     %rax,%rax
inc     %rax

ret                          ret
```

So far so good.

However, now I want to look at the said offsets:

```
16
24
32
64   <-- why 64 here?
48
56
64   <-- Oops 64 again?
```

I think that is the culprit. You save two registers at the same address.

Now strangely enough in the gdb output it looks correct. So I guess you did not show us your original source.

To avoid such problems, it is generally better to define your structure with define instructions defining the different offsets.

Otherwise, could you describe your context a little more. This does not look like code you could run with an OS, yet you mention gdb, so it sounds like you would be running in Linux. There are two possibilities I can think of: your context gets overwritten before the restore happens, the stack after the save changes a lot (I would imagine) and when you restore you end up with a completely different stack, yet you restore `%esp` to what now is "random data" as far as the stack is concerned. So the ret should work (you restore that much) but after that... who knows!

---

Update from questions in the comment:

> 1) Yes i am running on linux because the 32version of this was working fine and I guessed so will this .. Am i wrong to assume that ??

Ah. It could be that the stack is managed differently, but if you call your functions yourself, then that should not matter here. Also you modify rdx which may not be allowed?

> 2) I see what you mean by context getting overwritten in the code somewhere. So I tried placing save and restore immediately after each other. Still it gives me segmentation fault which means something is wrong in my assembly code.

Actually, your code would look something like this:

```
  MOV ..., %rdi
  CALL save
  TEST %rax
  JNE done
  [...do things, but no RET...]
  MOV ..., %rdi
  CALL restore
  ---not reached---
done:
  RET
```

When you return from the save function, the return address that you saved is right after the `CALL save`, which is why you `%rax` to 0 or 1 so you know whether you are returning from the save or the restore. Up to here, I do not see a problem.

The one thing I can think of would be that %rdi changes between the save and restore calls, but if you changed your code to do just those two calls, I would imagine that is not the case. Does it SEGV where the `=>` is indicated in your question? Or would it SEGV on the line before?

> 3) How to debug such errors ?

I would trace using `stepi` and verify that exactly what you expect happens on each instruction. See that the stack pointer saved is the one you get back in the restore and see that the return address is correct.

GDB can be used to `print` a set of entries each time you run a command. So if you do that and then `stepi` + enter any number of time after that, you should see your info on each step and see when it goes awry. (i.e. print registers and data at %rdi?)

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yes i had changed the source code and forgot to make the change here .The GDB outputs are the latest one as you pointed out. Few questions !!

1) Yes i am running on linux because the 32version of this was working fine and i guessed so will this .. Am i wrong to assume that ?? 

2) I see what you mean by context getting overwritten in the code somehwere . So i tried placeing save and restore immediately after each other. Still it gives me segmentation fault which means something is wrong in my assembly code .

3) How to debug such errors ?

Comment: (i.e. print registers and data at %rdi?) .. i tried this .. and yes indeed the value of rdi changes. But that happens for i386(32bit) also :: I do change the input parameter ..so in 32bit case 4(esp) changes for save and restore. The two inputs are their in my question (context and new_context). Why is it working for 32bit then ? I want to switch to new context, is it possible ?
mov 4(esp)  eax

 **/*
     * Switch to the new context.  This does not return.
     */
    cpu_restore_context (new_context);
**

Comment: You did not show us your 32bit version, but if rdi is not pointing at the exact same place, how can it restore things the same way since you use the exact same offsets for the `save` and `restore`?! `mov %rsp, 64(%rax)` must correspond 1 to 1 to `mov 64(%rax), %rsp`, right?

Comment: I have added 32bit version. Have a look. In 32bit also 4(%esp) is not the same on restore.. Have a look and let me know if my conversion is correct

Comment: Actually if `4(%esp)` never changes, then you have the same pointer in %eax in the save and the restore. So that is your culprit. `%rdi` needs to remain the same in your 64bit version. Maybe you could push it on the stack before calling `save` and then retrieve it from `8(%rsp)` instead of using `%rdi`?

Comment: Now how do i accomplish that. I tried adding push %rdi and then mov 8(%rsp) %rax inside save function. It gave me a segmentation fault ...    

0x0000000000424c1c <+0>:     push   %rdi
   0x0000000000424c1d <+1>:     mov    0x8(%rsp),%rax
=> 0x0000000000424c22 <+6>:     mov    %rbx,0x10(%rax)

Comment: (gdb) x/i (0x7fffffffe490)
   0x7fffffffe490:      (bad) 

rax memory location is 0x7fffffffe490

Comment: If the stack pointer is not the same when you call restore then it wouldn't work either. And if the stack is more negative when calling the restore, then saving `%rdi` on the stack would not be useful at all. So I'm not too sure how you can do this. Especially without seeing more of what your code does in between. And that might be a lot of code!

Comment: The code actually does a context switch..so rdi wont be same in both cases.. it switches between two different threads.. I am positive we wont have same rdi values.. Any idea if something else could be wrong ??

Comment: Well... if your code is not re-entrant (i.e. where it calls itself) then one way would be to save %rdi in a global variable. `mov %rdi, some address` So on restore you can do `mov some address,%rdi`. If it has to be re-entrant, then that would not work, obviously. Although if you have a single thread and when entering once you have to exit that child before the parent, then your global space can have multiple entries and a pointer to where you're current at (a stack of your own, in other words.)

Comment: The instruction causing the seg fault very strongly implies that the restored `sp` is junk.  Work backward from there.  Figure out a way to sanity check the stack pointer coming out of the context record, either in the debugger or with assertion code that emits useful information somewhere when an inconsistency is found.